# Paypal : "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount"

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

This form was working fine until today, suddenly, when you try to use it you get this error message: "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount."

I couldn't find any useful help anywhere. Would someone please tell me what's wrong. Thank you!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="EMAIL@gmail.com">

  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5,00" data-alertOnHover="Com €5.00 ajuda a pagar a deslocação de um animal." data-alertAfter="O seu donativo será de €"><span>€05.00</span></label>
  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="20,00" data-alertOnHover="€20.00 alimentam um cão durante duas semanas." data-alertAfter="O seu donativo será de €"><span>€20.00</span></label>
  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="40,00" data-alertOnHover="€40.00 pagam despesas médicas como a vacinação." data-alertAfter="O seu donativo será de €"><span>€40.00</span></label>
  <label class="input-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="80,00" data-alertOnHover="Com €80,00 podemos pagar uma esterilização." data-alertAfter="O seu donativo será de €"><span>€80.00</span></label>
  <span class="input-container">
    <input type="number" class="textBox" name="amount" placeholder="€ Outro" data-alertOnHover="Introduza o montante que gostaria de doar..." data-alertAfter="O seu donativo será de €" size="20">
  </span>

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Louzanimales_Donation_WPS_PT">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.WEBSITE.pt/THANKYOUPAGE.htm">

  <br style="clear: both;" />
  <input class="donation-button" type="submit" value="Enviar Donativo">

</form>
```

-

```
<script>
    var defaultTxt = $('#alert').text();
    var checked;
    $('input.checkbutton').change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".textBox").val("");
        $('#alert').text($(this).attr("data-alertAfter") + $(this).val());
        checked = $(this);
      }
      else
      {
        $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
        checked = undefined;
      }
      $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    $('.input-container').hover(
      function() {
        $('#alert').text($(this).children('input').attr("data-alertOnHover"));
      },
      function() {
        if (checked)
            $('#alert').text($(checked).attr("data-alertAfter") + $(checked).val());
        else
            $('#alert').text(defaultTxt);
      }
    );
    $(".textBox").focus(function() {
      checked = undefined;
        $(".checkbutton").prop("checked", false)
    }).blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") {
        checked = $(this);
        $('#alert').text($(this).attr("data-alertAfter") + $(this).val())
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to debug the Paypal API. It's possible Paypal is providing other JSON based on what you send/receive.

Comment: Amount should not be in comma but dot.

Comment: I've tried already having the amount with a dot and also with nothing at all. For the record while this was working what I had there was a comma.